# Trouble importing Openslide

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, pythonpath, openslide

I am trying to import openslide in a jupyter notebook, but I am repeatedly getting this error. I am getting the same error when I try to import by running python in terminal also.

```
ImportError: Couldn't locate OpenSlide dylib.  Is OpenSlide installed?
```

I ran `brew install openslide` and `pip install openslide-python`. It seems like it may be a path problem, but I am unsure how to fix it. My homebrew folder is in `/opt/homebrew` and my anaconda folder is in `/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3`. My python path contains all of these paths (see below). Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you!

```
/Users/myname
/opt/homebrew
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/Users/myname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locket-0.2.1-py3.8.egg
```

Comment: did you manage to sort it?

Answer (score 0):

In your activated conda environment, try: `conda install openslide` then `pip install openslide-python`.